# Stylecop is interfering with EfBundle creation in docker image in gitlab CI

Tags: asp.net-core, gitlab-ci, stylecop, ef-core-6.0

I have stylecop configured in my project and when I run
RUN dotnet ef migrations bundle --project
{CSPROJ_PATH}.csproj -r alpine.3.7-x64 --self-contained --configuration Bundle -o /build/migrationbundle --verbose
to create ef bundle for my docker image in gitlab CI, I get stylecop errors and it fails to create EF bundle.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stwDU.png)

How can I generate EF bundle while creating docker image in gitlab CI or how can I disable stylecop for only generating efbundle step in gitlab CI

Answer (score 0):

I was using the latest beta version `1.2.0-beta.556` of `StyleCop.Analyzers` NuGet package and I had similar problem.

Fixed the problem by upgrading .NET SDK Docker image to the latest version.

In my particular case upgrade was: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet/sdk:8.0` -> `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0.203`